# Data not being passed to view controller when pushed

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, properties

I have a tableviewcontroller with data population it. I'm trying to get a new details view to be pushed when the user taps on a cell. I can get the view to load, however the labels to show the data in more detail are not updated. Here is the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

SearchDetailViewController *controller = [self.storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"searchDetailVC"];
Events *event = [events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:event.eventDate];

controller.title=event.eventName; //ONLY ONE THAT WORKS!


controller.eventName.text = event.eventName;
controller.eventAddress.text = event.eventAddress;
controller.eventDate.text = dateString;
controller.eventTime.text = event.eventTime;
controller.ratingView.image = [self imageForRating:event.eventRating];
controller.eventDistance.text = @"NOT YET IMPLEMENTED";

[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

The only property that is set is the title of the NavigationController navbar. Am I doing something drastically wrong?

Comment: are eventName, eventAddress etc outlets pointing to elements in the view? looks like the view isn't being loaded at the point you push the new controller. maybe store them in instance vars of the view controller, then set the UI elements in `viewDidLoad`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass data like this. ViewController.domainField is nil at that time because the view hasn't loaded yet, and the label/TextField  is created when the view loads (via a nib) and not as soon as the view controller object is created.

This code can help you

```
SearchDetailViewController.h
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    @interface SearchDetailViewController : UIViewController 
    {

        NSString*  eventNameString ;
        NSString* eventAddressString;
        ...........
        .............

    }
    @property (nonatomic,retain) NSString*  eventNameString ;
    @property (nonatomic,retain) NSString*  eventAddressString;
    ...............
    ...............
    @end


SearchDetailViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     eventName.text=eventNameString;
     eventAddress.text=eventAddressString;
     ..........................
     ..........................
    eventNameString=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:@""];
}


TableView.m

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

SearchDetailViewController *controller = [self.storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"searchDetailVC"];
Events *event = [events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:event.eventDate];

controller.title=event.eventName; //ONLY ONE THAT WORKS!


controller.eventNameString=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:event.eventName];
controller.eventAddressString=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:eventAddress];
...............................
...............................
............

[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

Likewise, you have to pass all data from one view to another view - you can't directly assign to controller.

Comment: Thanks, i've implemented that, but when the code gets to the line `[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];` I get the error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<SearchDetailViewController 0x7c95210> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key buyButton.'`. Now I've deleted all references to this button (it was on the cell) and even deleted the button itself. Why is this even being referred to?